# Bootstrap with SASS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to use SASS version of Bootstrap 3, but the JS modules not working.

My bootstrap.js:

```
//= require bootstrap/affix
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/button
//= require bootstrap/carousel
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/tab
//= require bootstrap/transition
//= require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap/tooltip
//= require bootstrap/popover
```

What is `require` and how does it work? I never seen that before with the `normal`bootstrap.

Comment: That is a Rails require Syntax, basically it's like SASS Import query to import partials.

Comment: How can I work with them?

Comment: Answer provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same issue with them partials, I'd recommend you roll Bootstrap 3 out in a separate minified BS3 File, however if you wish to keep them in partials use the following in a separate Javascript file...

```
var includeFiles = [
    'affix',
    'alert',
    'button',
    'carousel',
    'collapse',
    'dropdown',
    'tab',
    'transition',
    'scrollspy',
    'modal',
    'tooltip',
    'popover'
];

for(var i=0; i < includeFiles.length; i++) {
    $('body').append($('<script src="partials/'+includeFiles[i]+'"></script>'));
}
```

Of course the Path inside the .append method is entirely dependant on your file structure, please edit that to suit your needs.

However if you really want to work with those require statements, then use the Rails Framework you can read on that at http://rubyonrails.org/

Comment: This is a little bit strange for me to add js files with a `for`. I would like to know, what is the best practice to use these files.

Comment: That method was provided to me by a senior developer a few years back on a similar issue, there may be better, however thats mostly raw Javascript, clean and readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript manifest, which is used by Rails to load Bootstrap plugins.
With this manifest, you can quickly disable a single plugin.

If you don't use Rails, you have 2 options :

### Load every plugin you need

```
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
...
```

### Use the compiled version of `bootstrap.js`

You can find it on Bootstrap CDN :

- http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.js
- http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js (minified)

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

(Include the distant script, or copy/paste it into you project)

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to understand the problem. I thought Bootstrap is for simple html/css development, but it seems Rails developer's use it too.

Comment: Web developers use tools/frameworks to increase their productivity, like Rails... or SASS ! That doesn't mean they're not making HTML/CSS/JS anymore, they're just making it better, faster, stronger.